# Does JQuery have a "move" function? Or is there a more compact way of doing this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using JQuery in conjunction with a content management system, I find myself often writing snippets of code such as

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var thishtml = $('#some-element')[0].outerHTML;
    $('#some-element').remove();
    $('#hmpg-btm-box-holder').prepend(thishtml);
});
```

Does JQuery have a functionality to accomplish that in a more compact fashion?

Comment: "If a single element ... is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned)" http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should suffice:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#hmpg-btm-box-holder').prepend($('#some-element'));
});
```

I'd avoid using `outerHTML` whenever possible (and preferably `innerHTML` also, unless you e.g. receive some HTML from a trusted server via AJAX and want to include it in the document).

Converting an element from an `Element` to a string (HTML) representation and back into an `Element` can easily cause unwanted effects like removing all event handlers attached to it.

Comment: Upvote for commentary regarding DOM element to string conversion.

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple one-liner to insert/move a single DOM element as first child of another element.

```
$('#hmpg-btm-box-holder').prepend($('#some-element'));
```

Or if you want to attach as last child:

```
$('#hmpg-btm-box-holder').append($('#some-element'));
```

Note that in both cases, the DOM element specified in the parameter will be removed from existing location in DOM if applicable.

This only applies to selectors which resolve to a single DOM element.  The behavior is a bit different for case where collections are passed as a parameter, so reference the function documentation to better understand that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.replaceWith()`.

```
$('.original').replaceWith('.new');
```

Comment: That's very useful to know about. Thanks.